# switching between wacom and mouse

Tags: scripting, interface, workflow, customization

It get crazy while switching between wacom and mouse as they need different kind of button actions or say "user preferences"

> For Example in wacom i can zoom using side touch strip. So free the midlle button click for special menu like "w". But to do this i need to change preference every time i switch.

Is there any quick or automatic way to blender can find whether i am using mouse or wacom pen and change between "user preferences"

Or any other work around?

Comment: I don't experience any problems like this. When I use my Wacom tablet, then go back to my mouse, everything is a seamless transition. What kind of button actions are you talking about?

Comment: Please check the added explanation

Answer (score 3):

On Windows and Mac, the Control Panel for wacom in the operating system allows you to set the behavior for different applications, both for the pen buttons and the touch strip. Create a setting for blender and just remap your buttons to do what you need.

[image]

Other trick I use is enable **Emulate 3 Button Mouse** That way clicking and dragging the pen while holding **<kbd>Alt</kbd>** key I can **rotate** the view.
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>** to **zoom** in and out. **<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>** to move sideways and up down. I've never used the mouse in blender at all...

[image]

For linux it is also possible to remap the buttons settings, but the changes are system-wide, not for specific applications.

Comment: I am aware of this option and setting and i use it already. What i I want to know is if there is an automated method or a shortcut key to toggle "presents" and "Blender key conf" at once between "mouse mode" (my custom presets and key conf for using blender with mouse ) and "Wacom pen mode" (my custom presets and key conf for using blender with wacom)

Answer (score 1):

I just started to use my Wacom Intuos one week ago and I have not disconnected my 3 button gaming mouse. With Blender 2.8 I discovered that using the lower button of the tablet (equivalent to the middle mouse button) I can rotate the view, pressing Shift at the same time I can move the scene to the sides and pressing control I can zoom in and out. It is not necessary to change anything from the configuration and I can switch to the mouse if I want without any problem. My OS is GNU/Linux Debian 10 and my desktop is Mate.